# Best way to deploy multiple client websites by Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to create wagtail websites for my clients. The websites will be identical and have the same features, but the templates should be different. Every time I update a feature to a new version, all websites will get the latest version automatically. By this approach, I don't need to deploy new feature versions (or base website version) to my clients separately.  I just need to deploy once and all clients will get the latest website version.  I will use the '[Multi-instance](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/multi_site_multi_instance_multi_tenancy.html#multi-instance)' feature of Wagtail which seems to fit my needs.

In the documentation on 'Multi-instance' it states:

> multiple sites share the same, single set of **project files**.
> Deployment would update the single set of **project files** and reload
> each instance.

https://www.accordbox.com/blog/add-bootstrap-theme-wagtail/

Let's say I want to have two different blog templates (different Bootstrap themes) in this tutorial.  The blog template file is 'post_page.html', and is a **project file**, so it will be deployed once, and all websites will get the same template in the 'Multi-instance' feature of Wagtail.

So my question is:

How can I deploy one blog template (post_page.html) to one client website, & another blog template to another client website?

Comment: Are you familiar with django-environ and environment files?  If not, I would suggest first looking at that library.  How do you manage your virtual environments?  And on what platform will you be deploying for production?  NGINX/uWSGI, Apache, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will want to include all the template variations in your code base and then choose which one to use at request time. To choose a template file dynamically, you create a [get_template](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/topics/pages.html#dynamically-choosing-the-template) method.

So the question becomes how do you configure which site uses which template(s). I would suggest looking into [wagtail.contrib.settings](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/settings.html) for a place to map a site to its templates. Where I work we support 3 variations - but they come as a set. You can't pick the blog template from A and mix with the calendar template from B. We do this for our own sanity - especially since many of our blocks support display options of their own; for example, the [3 display options here](https://qa.sites.caltech.edu/people-blocks) are just styles the user can choose for the same block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach (converted from [Phoebe Factorial's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681580/886938) for Multi-Site Wagtail.)

```
class SitePage(Page):
    def get_template(self, request):
        template_name = super().get_template(request)
        DOMAIN = settings.DOMAIN

        return [
            settings.DOMAIN + '/' + template_name,
            template_name,
        ]

    class Meta(Page.Meta):
        abstract = True


class BlogPage(SitePage):
    ...
```

this would look for the template in the following ordered locations:

1. templates/<module>/<DOMAIN>/<template_name>
2. templates/<module>/<template_name>

Of course, if you'd prefer not to default to a generic template, you could remove the second item in the return list for SitePage.